# Talk to VM through host operating system

Tags: java, linux, ant, vmware, virtualization

I have here a Windows distribution server that runs an ANT task to build enterprise software. What I need to do is to have the ANT task copy and run a VM image (Linux), and then...talk to that Linux VM through the host operating system (through the ant task itself). We need to be able to send files and/or commands to it.

Is there a practical way to go about this? I know that we already have a way to send commands to VMs that are also running Windows (so windows-windows interaction) -- but is there a way to do a windows-linux interaction?

Comment: which vm-technology do you use?  vmware has scripts allowing you to interact with both the vmware container, but also the OS inside.

Comment: we're using vmware server. would you happen to have some links to that material by any chance? I'd love to learn to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ssh is probably the simplest. There is an [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) for that. [Scp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) is also there to copy files

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented the thing you wanted. Of course, for my own purposes, and then just found this question by googling on keywords "vmware" and "ant".

https://github.com/zhuravlik/ant-vix-tasks

This is the taskset for Ant to manage VMWare VMs.
It works via VIX API, so Linux guests should be supported by it.

I did not test it with VMWare Server, though. Only with Workstation.
But the API is common, so it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what you need to do, but:

- The Linux system could expose an SSH server, and the host can do just about anything it needs to via SSH.
- The Linux system could expose a web service that the host consumes.
- The Linux system could expose a Samba share which the host then connects to and reads/writes from (if all you need to do is deal with some files, but that seems unlikely).

There are probably dozens of options.